# WildFly 10 https not working

Tags: wildfly-10

My application is deployed in WildFly10.

the following http link works:
http://localhost:8080/myapp

However, https is not working: 
https://localhost:8443/myapp

Security realm in my WildFly 10 standalone.xml are set as below:

```
<security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
```

and socket binding group is as below:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

In standalone.xml file, https-listner has been mentioned as below:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Please help my to access my app in https.

Comment: using postman i am able to access the https uRL. So, it seems https working.

Comment: I am accessing a REST API deployed in same app as below via the Java class.                                                                                                   
"https://localhost:8443/rest/refresh?key=";  Now the java class throwing unable to connect:  javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request

Comment: java -Dime.host=localhost -Dime.port=8443 -jar refresh.jar Refresher  is working.   But not the command when i am passing the Ip java -Dime.host=127.0.0.1 -Dime.port=8443 -jar refresh.jar Refresher